# Detect Windows version correctly (when using a generated app manifest)

Tags: .net, windows, clickonce, .net-4.7

I want to be able to tell the Windows version during the app execution.
According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-osversioninfoexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks), to differentiate between Windows 8.1+ and Windows 8, I need to [target the application using manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/targeting-your-application-at-windows-8-1).

> Applications not manifested for Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 will return the Windows 8 OS version value (6.2).

The problem is, my application uses ClickOnce deployment and has a generated manifest. I haven't found any place to configure the compatibility / supported OS versions. Is it something to be set in the .csproj file? If so, what syntax should I use? Pasting the manifest tags from documentation results in an error.

Comment: Describe the problem you are trying to solve instead of describing the solution you had in mind.  Which can't work.

Comment: @HansPassant That's what I attempted in the first sentence (/paragraph): The main problems is that I need to get the correct Windows version -- 6.3 on Win 8.1 and 10.0 on Win 10.
The secondary problem arising when I follow the advice I found is that I don't know how to modify the contents of a generated application manifest.
What information shoud I add to make it more clear and describing?